Not able to connect to postgres container when running spring boot container. I want to do it without using docker-compose
I am trying to docerize my spring boot application which uses posgtres. I am running postgres containter and while running app image spring boot not able to connect the data base. Getting below error. I am not using docker-compose as of now.
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:346) ~[postgresql-42.7.3.jar!/:42.7.3]
        at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:54) ~[postgresql-42.7.3.jar!/:42.7.3]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:273) ~[postgresql-42.7.3.jar!/:42.7.3]
        at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:446) ~[postgresql-42.7.3.jar!/:42.7.3]
        at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:298) ~[postgresql-42.7.3.jar!/:42.7.3]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:137) ~[HikariCP-5.1.0.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:360) ~[HikariCP-5.1.0.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:202) ~[HikariCP-5.1.0.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:461) ~[HikariCP-5.1.0.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:550) ~[HikariCP-5.1.0.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:98) ~[HikariCP-5.1.0.jar!/:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:111) ~[HikariCP-5.1.0.jar!/:na]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar!/:6.5.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:437) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar!/:6.5.2.Final]
        at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.getIsolatedConnection(DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.java:46) ~[hibernate-core-6.5.2.Final.jar!/:6.5.2.Final]
        ... 130 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:682) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedFinishConnect(NioSocketImpl.java:542) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:592) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:327) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:751) ~[na:na]
        at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.createSocket(PGStream.java:243) ~[postgresql-42.7.3.jar!/:42.7.3]
        at org.postgresql.core.PGStream.<init>(PGStream.java:98) ~[postgresql-42.7.3.jar!/:42.7.3]
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:136) ~[postgresql-42.7.3.jar!/:42.7.3]
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:262) ~[postgresql-42.7.3.jar!/:42.7.3]
        ... 144 common frames omitted

my application.properties file
server.port=9500
spring.application.name=test_service
#database
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://${PGHOST:localhost}:${PGPORT:5432}/${POSTGRES_DB:test-dev1}
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD:abcd}

#JPA Config
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect


postgres docker run  command
docker run --network=bridge -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=root -e POSTGRES_DB=test-dev --name postgresdb -p 5051:5432 -d postgres:16.4

spring boot docker run command
docker run -it --name testservice -p 9100:9500 --network=bridge -e PGHOST=postgresdb -e PGPORT=5432 -e POSTGRES_DB=test-dev -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=root test_service

I tried using --network attribute. Also I Tried to run in different ports also tried --link

Based on the error message listing "localhost" as the attempted host, I would say that "PGHOST=postgresdb" did not have the intended effect in your SpringBoot container.

looks like it. but don't know what to do now

test_service is not a standard image.  Without knowing what it is, I don't see how anyone can help you.  Anyway, doesn't seem like a software development question.

You've got two unrelated problems here.
Application configuration
The fact that your testservice application is attempting to connect to localhost means that you're not correctly configuring the application; it looks as if the PGHOST variable isn't useful in the context of your application. Until you fix this problem, nothing else matters. You cannot reach postgres by connecting to localhost.
I don't know anything about your application framework; maybe environment variables aren't expanded in the configuration file? As a first pass, try replacing the environment variables with literal values:
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://postgresdb:5432/test-dev
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=secret

Once you have things working with literal values, then you can start looking into why variable expansion wasn't working as you expected.
Name lookups don't work on the default bridge network
Name lookups don't work on the default bridge network. One reason why docker compose is convenient is because it takes care of setting a user-defined network for you (and attaching your containers to it), but it doesn't do anything that we can't accomplish through other means.
You'll need to first create a user-defined network:
docker network create mynetwork

And then attached your containers to this network:
docker run --network=mynetwork --name postgresdb -d \
  -e POSTGRES_USER=postgres \
  -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=secret \
  -e POSTGRES_DB=test-dev docker.io/postgres:16.4

docker run -it --network=mynetwork --name testservice -p 9100:9500 test_service

Note that I've made a couple of changes here to your docker commands:

Both containers are attached to the mynetwork network.
I've removed the port publishing on the postgres container; you can put it back if you really need it, but typically your database only needs to be accessed by your service (for debugging you can always docker exec into the postgres container).
I've removed all the environment variables on the testservice container, since we're not using them at the moment.

The equivalent docker compose configuration to the above would be:
services:
  postgresdb:
    image: docker.io/postgres:16.4
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: secret
      POSTGRES_DB: test-dev

  testservice:
    image: test_service
    ports:
    - "9100:9500"
    tty: true
    stdin: true

This should work; if you'd like to update your question with a [mcve] that I can run to test things out I would be happy to give that a try.

i tried with creating new network but it didn't work out. let me test with literal and compose than I will update here

with postgres literal it is working.

I deleted build folder and created jar file again and it worked with env variable also.
